# Why does 128GB iPhone have 113GB capacity?

Tags: iphone, ios, storage

On the side of the iPhone packaging, Apple defines 1GB as 1,000,000,000 bytes (rather than 1,073,741,824 bytes), so you end up missing 9,438,953,472 bytes (~9GB) calculating it this way for 128GB of space (128,000,000,000 bytes is ~119GB).

My iPhone says that it has 113GB of capacity, but it should be 119GB, so where did the other 6GB disappear to?

Comment: Minor nitpick, but you're conflating [metric prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix) and [binary prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix). 128 GB is ~119 GiB.

Comment: Friendly nitpick of your nitpick: [JEDEC memory standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JEDEC_memory_standards#Unit_prefixes_for_semiconductor_storage_capacity).

Comment: @AndrewLarsson JEDEC is an American industry organization - nobody ever accused Americans of being reasonable when it comes to units, nor industry organizations (focused on semiconductors to boost) of having foresight and logical and forward-thinking specifications. SI is *the* international standards system, whose definition of *kilo* dates back to 1799, long before JEDEC existed.

Comment: You're looking at the difference between *giga*bytes (GB)  and *gibi*bytes (GiB or in some cases Gb). The gibibyte is 1,073,741,824 bytes; the gigabyte is 1,000,000,000.

Comment: @phihag Just because a standard is older doesn't mean it makes more sense :) And it's not like the international standard dates to 1799 - that's just when the term was codified *in France*. You could just as easily say that it dates to ancient greece, where "kilo" already meant "thousand" thousands of years ago :) Finally, *byte* is not an SI unit, and neither is it SI derived. While there's certain benefits to having common unit prefixes, we still use hours and days, don't we? :)

Comment: @Luaan Thanks for the pointer. *kilo* dates to ancient Greece, where *kilo* already meant 1000 thousands of years ago. Makes a lot of sense to me not to meddle with that clear and well-established definition, [lest we end up with dozens of definitions for the same unit name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mile).

Comment: @phihag And yet the very article you link to notes that `m` was used to refer to a mile in the past, but had to be changed to `mi` when SI units were introduced to avoid ambiguities. Everybody used `m` to mean something, but they had to change in response to the newly introduced standard (this has funny parallels with IE/NetScape and the HTML specification, among many others :P). If only there was one correct answer to each question, we could agree on everything, huh? :D

Answer (score 13):

The other 6 GB are OS itself. The given capacity is a value for the physical storage that the phone has, not the amount that can be used by the owner. iOS is about 6 GB in size on its own.

Also, the formatted capacity is less than the size of the chips that are manufactured into the device. It's in a very small footnote at the bottom of the [tech specs for each iOS device](http://www.apple.com/iphone-6s/specs/). Typically note #1

[image: picture of footnote]

As you can see on the following link, each OS differs between versions, device type and device size so the gap in specs to usable space isn't a fixed constant.

- [How large is iOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68796/how-large-is-ios)

Comment: Why doesn't Apple shows that capacity is 119GB and 6GB is used. Just like on Macs. Can you confirm that iOS excluded from capacity?

Comment: Using the larger value makes the phone seem to have more storage than it really does. A similar question is asked in [this thread](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68796/how-large-is-ios).

Comment: I do think that this is probably the right answer. But I can't find any confirmation at the moment. By the way, sometimes you can see on absolutely new devices that about 1GB is used.

Comment: @user1561346 I'll direct you to [chat] for discussions on _why_ Apple does X - it leads to speculation and generally is off topic for the main site.

Comment: @bmike I don't ask why Apple does something. The question is where did the space disappear. I just wanted to make it clear whether it's some kind of strange storage formatting or just iOS size is deducted from capacity.

Comment: By the way, if installed iOS 9 size is about 6GB, why does capacity of 16GB model is ~11.8GB when it should be 16 000 000 000 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 = 14.9GB - 6GB = 8.9GB.

Comment: The OS needs some space at runtime to operate.

Comment: @user1561346 You also need some data to store information about the data you're storing - the file system metadata. Typically, those scale with total capacity, so bigger drives also mean more capacity "lost" to those structures. Maybe that's included in the 6 GB figure, or maybe the system on the 16 GB model is simply different. Sadly, it's kind of hard finding technical details about anything Apple makes :/

Comment: @user1561346 Like the OS, updates require sufficient free space for a reason. It's using the same drive you use for personal content. https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT203097

Answer (score 2):

I believe iOS displays capacities in base-10 values as well, so iOS would show the raw space as 128GB. The 15GB difference (128-113) is due to both iOS and formatting, not a discrepancy between base-2 and base-10.

Comment: This has been my experience - a combination of losses to the filesystem, usage by system mandated files, and perhaps a very small storage controller component should make up the total.

Answer (score 1):

To simply put, it is used by the Operating System. All that code would have to go somewhere, right? Also, if you notice, with every new major update they try to cut down that space. Even if you write a simple program, it would take up some memory from your computer. It is the same concept for cell phones as well.

Answer (score -1):

The OS needs that space, operating systems take up lots of space